# How can I populate a ListView(TwoWayView) with json?

Tags: android, json, listview

I have a json saved at the apps data folder which I want to use to populate a listview with.

The json structure is basic:

```
{
    "someList": [
        {
            "first": "First Item"
            "second": "Second Item"
        },
        {
            "first": "Third Item",
            "second": "Fourth Item"
        },
        {
            "first": "Fifth Item",
            "second": "Sixth Item"
        }
    ]
}
```

In my I just set a hardcoded text with

```
viewHolder.first.setText("First Item");
viewHolder.second.setText("Second Item");
```

Is there any way to have it retrieve the data from the stored json file?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes there is a way.

Here are the steps:

1. Load the file from the directory

   ```
   InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json_file);
   Writer writer = new StringWriter();
   char[] buffer = new char[1024];
   try {
       Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
       int n;
       while ((n = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
          writer.write(buffer, 0, n);
      }
   } finally {
       is.close();
   }
   String jsonString = writer.toString();
   ```
2. Convert this into JSON you can go through

   ```
   JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
   JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("someList");
   ```
3. Now enumerate through the items in the list and add them to the ViewHolder

   ```
   for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        viewHolder.first.setText(curr.getString("first"))
        viewHolder.second.setText(curr.getString("second"))
        //...now add each viewholder as an object and you're done
   }
   ```

Comment: That got me halfway there. The list loads, but only the last item gets put into the listview. It's repeated as many times as the jsonarray has items in it.

Comment: This is correct way. Just change to use data position to get json object from json array instead of for loop: 'JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position);'

Comment: @Carl. The last bit is to make the ViewHolder as part of your list. Add the code you have to add an item to the list into the for loop and you should be good

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse your *json* either manually using the Java `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` or using a parsing library like `gson` from *google* .
https://github.com/google/gson